# Need help on applying drop shadow effects to a pdf box components in java

Tags: java, pdf, fabricjs, pdfbox, dropshadow

**Work Story:** Need to convert fabric js generated one page design json code to pdf file using java.

**Issue**: When i try to apply drop shadow to components like rectangle, circle or text i could not find any supported classes from [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) Library.

I am trying to explore how to apply drop shadow styles after creating components using [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) API.

Below is the code snippet for creating a rectangle. Need help after creating the component for applying drop shadow effects.

```java
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("imagepath",doc);
PDPage page = new PDPage();
doc.addPage(page);
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

int left = -60;
int top = 96;
int width = 471;
int height = 365;

contentStream.setStrokingColor(1, 0, 0);
contentStream.setLineWidth(4);

int imageOriginalWidth = 633;
int imageOriginalHeight = 422;

float scaleX = 0.99f;
float scaleY = 0.99f;

float imageWidth = imageOriginalWidth*scaleX;
float imageHeight = imageOriginalHeight*scaleY;

float imageY = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - (top + imageHeight-58); 
float imageX = -104; 
          
contentStream.addRect(left, page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - top - height,
        width, height);
contentStream.clip();
contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);
contentStream.close();

doc.save(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "dummy.pdf"));
doc.close();
```

Below image is expected output of drop shadow applied rectangle:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a drop shadow by first drawing a dark rectangle with transparency at a slight offset right before drawing your content. In your case e.g. like this:

```java
...
float imageWidth = imageOriginalWidth*scaleX;
float imageHeight = imageOriginalHeight*scaleY;

float imageY = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - (top + imageHeight-58); 
float imageX = -104; 

// vvv--- code added for shadow
PDExtendedGraphicsState extGS = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
extGS.setNonStrokingAlphaConstant(.2f);
contentStream.saveGraphicsState();
contentStream.setGraphicsStateParameters(extGS);
contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
contentStream.addRect(left + 5, page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - top - height - 5, width, height);
contentStream.fill();
contentStream.restoreGraphicsState();
// ^^^--- code added for shadow

contentStream.addRect(left, page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - top - height, width, height);
contentStream.clip();
contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);
contentStream.close();
...
```

*([AddDropShadow](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/AddDropShadow.java#L38) test `testRectangleWithDropShadow`)*

You might want to play around with different values for the alpha value (.2f), the color (BLACK), and the offsets (5 each) I used. Also I took the clip path as area to apply a shadow to. If your image does not fully fill that area, you might want to play around with the coordinates here.

Comment: Thanks for the above suggestion  and it is useful till some point and i will play around it. I can try for other components as well like circle and text...etc. Could you please also suggest on how to apply '_blur effect to the background rectangle_'.

Comment: Can anyone help here how can apply blur effect to [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) components like above attached image.

Comment: By *applying a blur effect to the background rectangle* do you mean the content underneath the shadow or do you mean the shadow itself (which is in the background to the image)? As far as I know PDF does not have a feature to blur arbitrary content, so option one does not appear to exist, but you can fade the shadow edges to make them appear softer.